# Usage of 'a' or 'an' after 'As'

Tags: grammar, adverbs, articles, conjunctions

Which is correct:

> - make it as information system for this company
> - make it as **an** information system for this company

I thought the second one sounds better but when I tried all spell/grammar checkers none of them marked the first one wrong.
When 'as' is used like this should it always be followed by 'a' or 'an'?

English is not my first language so pardon me for my mistakes.
I am in the process of making a thesis but stuck in this certain part so if anyone could help I'd be really grateful, thanks!

Comment: 2nd one is correct.

Comment: Quite apart from the capitalisation problem, *Make it as [an] information system for this company* doesn't look much like a credible "sentence". I can't really see it as an imperative (boss instructing programmer to set something up so it can be used as an information system?). The most credible context I can think of is something like *Your crappy database application will never make it as an information system for this company* (where *to make it = **to succeed***).

Comment: @lly i don't understand. Is the 2nd sentence wrong or i shouldn't use it before further discussion at the ell? it isn't the actual sentence but the usage is kinda similar. i only asked for a simple wrong or right because it's urgent and i don't understand how this forum works,sorry.

Comment: As it stands, the second sentence doesn't make any sense, even if it is somewhat better than the first one. You should add the rest of the sentences around it so the phrasing can be corrected.

Comment: @claire You don't want any old answer, you want the right answer, which people need more context to give (the entire sentence and an explanation of what you're trying to say). This should be fixed ASAP, and then moved to the right spot (the English Language Learners site).

Answer (score 1):

*As* doesn't change the rules you need for using articles with nouns.

Your noun phrase "information system" is:

- not plural
- not being used in the sense of describing a type or kind (you mean an actual instance of an information system)
- not being used abstractly or describing a concept (again, you mean an actual instance of an information system)
- not part of a well-known prepositional or other phrase that doesn't use articles (no preposition here)

so you need an article if you aren't using another determiner.

Here's an example where you would not use the article.

> A: Hey, what category should I enter the cost for this piece of fabric under.  Cloth or fabric?
>
> B: It looks like a hand towel.  Enter it as cloth.  (We mean the type or category "cloth")

The verb "make"  would rarely be used in this kind of context because "make" usually means to create an instance of X, so you are automatically not talking about X abstractly or as a type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using the verb 'make'

The rest of your second example would be fine with a different verb, such as 'Implement/adapt/install/develop it as an information system for this company.'

'information system' as a generic plural might sometimes escape withoutn an article.

'information system for this company' can only be singular, so it must have an article. If there's a choice of systems, it could take 'an'; if there's only one, specific system it must take 'the.'